# VSCode Flickering/Disappearing text after upgrade to Code 1.69.1

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, vmware-player

I have the similar problem of flickering text (more like disappearing text after I upgrade to Code 1.69.1). Attached is the image below showing the problem

[image: Flickering Text]

The flickering problem is dynamic ie various parts of text will show at some point then disappear after some time... there is no one point of time where all the text appear in the console

**Resolution**
I have tried to solve it by keying at the terminal: `code --enable-native-gpu-memory-buffers` and by `code --disable-gpu` but it does not solve the display problem.

The VS code is installed at a Ubuntu18.04 VM. I have checked with another similar VM (same configuration and settings), the same problem occurs.

- However when I check with the VS Code running on the host machine OS(running windows 10), it seem there is no such problem.
- I begin to suspect whether it is some linux files(the problem occurs after I run sudo apt-get update & upgrade, which also upgrade the code) that is affecting the VSCode. So for experimentation, I went ahead to try to upgrade the VSCode on another machine running the same VM (with the exception that I running a newer VMware player (v16 as opposed to v15) with it). There was no such problem. It works perfectly fine.

Information
I have tried to run `code --status`. Here is my findings

```
[7965:0714/084658.745148:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[8000:0714/084659.205337:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] renderergl_utils.cpp:188 (ClearErrors): Preexisting GL error 0x00000500 as of ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/gl/TextureGL.cpp, setImageHelper:256.
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
MESA-LOADER: failed to retrieve device information
[8000:0714/084659.573378:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.573719:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.573946:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.574163:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.574432:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.574712:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.574952:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.575217:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.575442:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.575692:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.575928:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.576155:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.576375:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.576534:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.576733:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.576939:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.577182:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.577396:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.577627:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.577850:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
[8000:0714/084659.578052:ERROR:gbm_wrapper.cc(275)] Failed to export buffer to dma_buf: No such file or directory (2)
Version:          Code 1.69.1 (b06ae3b2d2dbfe28bca3134cc6be65935cdfea6a, 2022-07-12T08:28:29.328Z)
OS Version:       Linux x64 5.4.0-122-generic
CPUs:             Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1505M v5 @ 2.80GHz (8 x 2807)
Memory (System):  7.74GB (0.39GB free)
Load (avg):       0, 0, 0
VM:               100%
Screen Reader:    no
Process Argv:     --unity-launch --crash-reporter-id af9edcb1-babf-40b9-bb72-ce9b845e3f92
GPU Status:       2d_canvas:                              enabled
                  canvas_oop_rasterization:               disabled_off
                  direct_rendering_display_compositor:    disabled_off_ok
                  gpu_compositing:                        enabled
                  multiple_raster_threads:                enabled_on
                  opengl:                                 enabled_on
                  rasterization:                          enabled
                  raw_draw:                               disabled_off_ok
                  skia_renderer:                          enabled_on
                  video_decode:                           disabled_software
                  video_encode:                           disabled_software
                  vulkan:                                 disabled_off
                  webgl:                                  enabled
                  webgl2:                                 enabled

CPU %   Mem MB     PID  Process
    0      143    6514  code main
    0       40    6519     zygote
    0       95    6554       gpu-process
    0       16    6573         broker
    0       40    6520     zygote
    0        0    6522       zygote
    0       55    6560     utility-network-service
    0      238    6572     window (Wahwah.h - audacity - Visual Studio Code)
    0      127    6621     shared-process
    0       63    6650       ptyHost
    0       63    6690       fileWatcher
    0      135    6634     extensionHost
    0       79    6757       /home/xmonster/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-1.10.8-linux-x64/bin/cpptools

Workspace Stats: 
|  Window (Wahwah.h - audacity - Visual Studio Code)
|    Folder (audacity): 6853 files
|      File types: py(1142) h(1059) cpp(729) png(599) ttl(530) c(366)
|                  trig(337) nt(220) nq(196) txt(127)
|      Conf files: cmake(41) sln(16) dockerfile(4) github-actions(2)
|                  makefile(1)
```

I am quite sure the problem have something to do with my display settings (as shown above it is not running well). However from here I do not really know how to proceed except to use the above display command to code

Need some help or suggestion here

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I am not too sure if this is the right solution but it seems to solve my problem... hope it helps the rest who face this issue

I have turned off the Accelerate 3D graphics option in the vmware for the particular VM that I am facing the problem. It works for now and all the text appear

Cheers